# Meteor - before Iron-Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Before the advent of Iron-Router, what was the best way to switch between views/templates?

Right now, I can href a new location and iron-router will render the desired template, like so:

```
Router.route('/about', function(){
  this.render('about_template',{to:'stuff'});
  this.render('personnel_template',{to:'stuff'});
}, {where:'client'});
```

But how is this accomplished without routes? Do I just render the view when a certain action happens and just manually change the URL location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First be sure you have the correct Layout template

```
<template name="layout">
{{> yield}}
</template>
```

and config like this.

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});
```

now try with this.

```
Router.route('/about', {name: 'about_template'});
```

and call like this on HTML.

```
href="{{pathFor 'about_template'}}"
```

Comment: I do not follow your code. Right now, my #about and #contact routes do nothing. So there URL changes when I click the navbar items, but nothing happens. How do I link events (like switching the templates) to those URL changes?

Comment: for example, how do I call "this.render()" outside of a iron-router function? right?

Comment: Router.go('/path') seems to be a server route not client-side

Comment: http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/ this solves my problem. Call Router.go('xyz'); along with                                                  Router.route('/posts/:_id', function () {
  this.render('Post');
}, {
  name: 'xyz'
});